# Dynamically update variables for Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

I currently have a Firebase Function and to do its task it needs a key. This key changes every 4-20 days and I want to be able to have the functions update the key themselves. What would the best way to do this be? To get the key it is a slow network call to a 3rd party API so I'd rather store it. Currently I have an environment variable that I change myself when I find the functions failing, but I would rather have this process done automatically.

I don't think I can change the environment variables at run time so is the only option to store the value in my database and query for that every time I need it? This seems a bit slow, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The GCP Secret Manager sounds like a great candidate ....

https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager

Using this, your cloud function can ask it for the current value of the key.  You can also update the key value separate from the function using APIs or script commands.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial in the past to solve problem like yours.....https://torbjornzetterlund.com/using-secret-manager-in-a-google-cloud-function-with-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the only option to store the value in my database and query for that every time I need it?

Cloud Functions is stateless and will not retain any information outside of the code and data that was deployed with the function.  So, you will need some sort of persistent storage to hold the key.  It doesn't have to be a database.  It can be any persistent storage you want.

You can certainly just read the key once (from wherever you choose to store it) and store it in memory if it was not previously read, for as long as you are allowed to keep using it without refreshing the value.  Memory does persist for some time per server instance, but it is not shared among all of your function invocations, as each one might run on a different instance.

Comment: Hi Doug, does Google Cloud provide any kind of persistent storage (in my case, for a large json config file) that can be stored in memory and read across multiple instances of the same Cloud Function? I have a similar use case to the original poster to dynamically update this without re-deploying my function and know I could use Admin SDK to read the config from Firebase, but am afraid of speed and cost. Does Cloud Storage provide anything that might help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As informed to me by Paul Rudin on the Google Cloud Slack, you could cache the key as a global variable which is, in practice, often reused: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations

> Use global variables to reuse objects in future invocations There is
> no guarantee that the state of a Cloud Function will be preserved for
> future invocations. However, Cloud Functions often recycles the
> execution environment of a previous invocation. If you declare a
> variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent
> invocations without having to be recomputed.
>
> This way you can cache objects that may be expensive to recreate on
> each function invocation. Moving such objects from the function body
> to global scope may result in significant performance improvements.
> The following example creates a heavy object only once per function
> instance, and shares it across all function invocations reaching the
> given instance:

```
// Global (instance-wide) scope
// This computation runs at instance cold-start
const instanceVar = heavyComputation();

/**
 * HTTP function that declares a variable.
 *
 * @param {Object} req request context.
 * @param {Object} res response context.
 */
exports.scopeDemo = (req, res) => {
  // Per-function scope
  // This computation runs every time this function is called
  const functionVar = lightComputation();

  res.send(`Per instance: ${instanceVar}, per function: ${functionVar}`);
};
```